# load property file from external path using spring

Tags: spring, wildfly-9

I have to read property file from WildFly which is outside war in wildfly using spring, i tried it using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in spring and it is working but there is one issue.

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:/C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\deployments\/propertyLoader.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="getPropertyBean"
    class="com.csc.loadProperty.GetProperty">
    <property name="prefixProp" value="${prefix}" />
    <property name="suffixProp" value="${suffix}" />
    <property name="newProp" value="${new}" />
</bean>
```

here i am giving absolute path for propertyLoader.properties, but i have to give relative path from the server as the path can be different for different machines. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring 4 , then specify property file path using ${}

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${app.home}/app.properties")
public class AppConfig 
 @Autowired
 Environment env;
}
```

Then set that app.home as system variable at startup. If you run spring application inside some container then set this property in the java startup options or vm arguments.

```
java -jar -Dapp.home="/home/dev/config" example.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:# C:/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments/propertyLoader.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```